# C (Linux) Checking socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm writting a client-server C project where the server processes messages from the client, and replicates them to a backup server. It works well, but one of the points of the project (its a university project) is to be prepared for errors, in this case - the backup server dying.

I have this on my replication function:

```
int table_skel_replicate(struct message_t *msg, int sockSecundario){
    char *msg_buf;
    int buf_size_net = 0;
    int buf_size=0; 
    int okk;

    struct sockaddr_in server;

    msg->opcode--;

    buf_size = message_to_buffer ( msg, &msg_buf ); 

    buf_size_net = htonl(buf_size);

    okk = write( sockSecundario, &buf_size_net, sizeof(int) );

    if(okk == -1 || okk == 0) {
        msg->opcode++;
        return okk; 
    }   

    okk = write_all ( sockSecundario, msg_buf, buf_size );

    if(okk == -1) {
        msg->opcode++;
        return okk; 
    }   

    okk = read ( sockSecundario, &buf_size_net, sizeof(int) );

    if(okk == -1 || okk == 0) {
        msg->opcode++;
        return okk; 
    }   

    buf_size = ntohl(buf_size_net);
    msg_buf = malloc ( buf_size );

    okk = read_all( sockSecundario, msg_buf, buf_size );

    msg->opcode++;

    return okk;
}
```

it was supposed to fail the first `write()` as soon as the backup server died. but it doesnt.
Instead, it proceds to the `write_all()` function (which is basicly a `write()` inside a `while` for long transfers) and dies on the first `write()` there. i tried using the `checksockopt()` function but it return the status as ok...

The main application simply closes. Any help appreciated...

Comment: You need to check **every** call to `write()` for errors, the backup server can die any time between any pair of `write()` calls.  Make sure your code gracefully handles every possible failure.

Comment: It's possible for a write to succeed after a connection has gone down at the other end, due to buffering. A subsequent write will eventually fail. That's why you need to check all `write()` returns, not just one.

Comment: OP does seem to check his `write` returns - presumably in `write_all` as well.  The question is what makes OP so sure exactly what write this should fail on.  The first write may succeed but elicit the RST and then it is the subsequent write that will fail with EPIPE.  So this may be expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your checks of the `write()` calls presumably are not effective because the program terminates due to SIGPIPE. [man 2 write](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write):

> *fd* is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is
>   closed. When this happens the writing process will also receive a
>   **SIGPIPE** signal. (Thus, the write return value is seen only if
>   the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)

To easily avoid this, replace every

```
    write( sockSecundario, …, … )
```

by

```
    send(sockSecundario, …, …, MSG_NOSIGNAL)
```